# is it required to use CDN for small videos on Hero banner?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, cdn, google-index

I am trying to upload video on my hero banner.Video will always run on loop and has no audio.i read lots of article and  one point which is common in all is using CDN.

Is it really required  to use CDN for 20 to 25 sec video?

what are other good practices to use video on hero banner which help to load site faster and help in indexing the page.

Comment: CDN is not a requirement if you are doing a small project. Yes, loading time might take a hit, but it is not something you should be worrying about. In case you are talking about a bigger userbase, yes, you should load any resource from CDN wherever possible.

Comment: thanks @Prajwal for the clarification i am really  new to this can you confirm one more thing  can we set cdn only specefic to videos .i am working on large website which have quite good load time now and i want to add video on homepage if I dont use CDN does my load time will get affected?

Comment: @Prajwal and can you also suggest some good practices to use vidoe on Homepage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PurviJha You need to ask about a specific **programming** issue (_eg:_ errors in your code or having a coding concept explanation like For loop versus While loop). You cannot ask about something you did not show. In future, put a link to a page that has demo of problem in action or else just show code that recreates the problem. You'll get faster Answers that way. Thanks.